# unistd.h's chdir gives undefined reference to symbol 'chdir@@GLIBC_2.2.5' on linux

Tags: c++, linux, chdir, unistd.h

When linking some object files together using `ld`, an error occurs:

> `undefined reference to symbol 'chdir@@GLIBC_2.2.5'`

> `undefined reference to symbol 'setlocale@@GLIBC_2.2.5'`

Do I need to link a library for this function?
The [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/chdir) does not say anything about linking.

Comment: How do you compile and link the application?

Comment: my guess would be you're trying to link to a static library which was built for a newer version of libc than the version you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and C++ share a notion of what a *standard library* is: it is a bunch of libraries that are always available in the C (or C++) build tool.

The problem is that `ld` is a far more generic tool: it can be used to link C, C++, Fortran, assembly language, etc. The compilers know how to pass specific options to the loader to ask it to find the relevant libraries, but when you directly use `ld`, **you** have to pass them explicitely.

Alternatively, avoid using `ld` and always use `c++` (or `g++` or whatever name your compiler is called) even for simply linking.